# Swift enable and disable time picker past time based on user input date

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

In my scenario, I am validating user input current `date` or different date based on it I need to enable and disable in time picker past time restriction. If user input current date then need to restrict past time in time `picker` otherwise need to show all `time` list.

**My Code Below**

```
// MARK: Validate Current Date or Not Based on it Need to enable and disable timepicker past time

        let dateCurrents = Date()
        let formatters = DateFormatter()
        formatters.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let resultDate = formatters.string(from: dateCurrents)

        if fullDate == resultDate {
            print("Same Date Past Time Disabled")
            let nows = Date()
            timePickerView.minimumDate = nows
            timePickerView.date = nows
        } else {
            print("Different Date Past Time Enabled")
            timePickerView.minimumDate =
            timePickerView.date =  // Need to Enable Past Time
        }
```

Comment: So what is the problem/your question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if user input `fullDate` date and my `resultDate` system date same need to allow time picker past time disable function. otherwise need to show all time list. how to achieve this?

Comment: just set `minimumDate = nil`, then you get no minimum date.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen what about  `timePickerView.date`? Is there anything I need to set `nil` ?

Comment: No, `date` is just the currently selected value, whereas `minimum` and `maximum` date the allowed range specify (if set to a value != `nil`)

Comment: @AndreasOetjen above logic is if `fullDate` (user selected date from calendar) and 'resultDate' (Current system date) if both are same need to set `minimumDate = currentdate`  otherwise need to show past time in Timepicker. This is the functionality I need to achieve.

Comment: Could you explain which data your variables hold? How do you get `fullDate`? Is this a user input from a `UITextField`, or why are you working with strings?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen actually user selecting calendar date based on it, I am getting `fullDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
let fullDate = datePickerView.date
let now = Date()

let calendar = Calendar.current
let result = calendar.compare(now, to: fullDate, toGranularity: .day)
let isSameDay = result == .orderedSame

if isSameDay {
    print("Same Date Past Time Disabled")
    timePickerView.minimumDate = now
    timePickerView.date = now
} else {
    print("Different Date Past Time Enabled")
    timePickerView.minimumDate = nil
    timePickerView.date = now
}
```